# SessionNotCreatedException: session not created from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created
>   from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer (Session info:
>   chrome=69.0.3497.92) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609545
>   (c2f88692e98ce7233d2df7c724465ecacfe74df5),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.5
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 2.58 seconds Build info:
>   version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time:
>   '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z' System info: host: 'MyMacPro', ip:
>   'fe80:0:0:0:80f:598d:12ad:19e7%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch:
>   'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.5', java.version: '10.0.1' Driver info:
>   driver.version: ChromeDriver

I tried with upgrading/down grading chrome and Chromedriver, still getting same issue

Request to help me on this?

Here is the code used for driver creation:

```
public class TestTHis {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {      

      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/raghavendern/Downloads/chromedriver");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
      Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
      WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
      searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
      searchBox.submit();
      Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
      driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us more information. For example, how i your setup method? or driver initializing method.

Comment: added the code in the body:

Comment: did you tried to downgrade/upgrade the chrome browser version?

Comment: Issue got resolved after adding localhost 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts file